# It is possible to use the Exchange 2010 web client with an Exchange 2007 mail server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, windows-sbs

We are evaluating our options to upgrade our Windows SBS 2003 server. We are considering Windows SBS 2008, which comes with Exchange 2007 and an extra Windows Server 2008 Standard license.

If we also bought Exchange 2010, could we install it on the Windows Server 2008 Standard machine and use the web client in combination with the Exchange 2007 server (that would be hosting the mailboxes)?

Is that a supported server role for Exchange 2010? I remember reading about so called front-end server configurations, but I have no experience with that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Exchange 2010 as a [Client Access server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124915.aspx) with Exchange 2007 - see the relevant [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124350.aspx) article.

I'm pretty sure you can't use a second Exchange server if you are using SBS, it will be one of the limitations that MS impose.